# WLAN using Netgear WNA1000M fails - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: raspbian, wireless, networking

I am trying to connect my RPi to my WLAN, but I fail. The network connection works when I use a cable. The RPi was bought about two weeks ago, and I am using a recent (I don't know exactly which) version of Raspbian.

My router is an AVM Fritzbox 7270 running a WPA/WPA2-secured wireless network with a public SSID and DHCP enabled. The network key is a number with 16 digits.

The wireless network is found if I type `iwlist wlan0 scan`. The wireless network adapter being used is a Netgear WNA1000M. The adapter is listed if I type `ifconfig`, but it has no IP address assigned.

I updated the `/etc/network/interfaces` file according to the information I found on the web. Now the file looks like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wpa-ssid MYSSID
wpa-psk MYPSK

iface default inet dhcp
```

For `MYSSID` and `MYPSK` I entered the SSID of my network (without quotes) and the value I got from the `wpa_passphrase` command (also without quotes).

The file looked originally like this:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

When I reboot my RPi, the blue led of the wireless adapter flashes for about one second, then turns off again, and I can not access my RPi in a wireless way.

Once I connect it to the cable, I am able to access it using SSH again.

The last lines of `dmesg` are:

```
[    3.010438] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.036171] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    3.098577] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:85:47:8d
[    3.213348] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.325470] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0846, idProduct=9041
[    3.343128] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.363116] usb 1-1.3: Product: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
[    3.370586] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    3.393128] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[    3.843420] udevd[137]: starting version 175
[    6.484503] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[    9.612649] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   10.076909] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   10.838719] bcm2835 ALSA card created!
[   10.852938] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.865355] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.871429] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.882875] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.891016] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.899001] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   10.906941] bcm2835 ALSA chip created!
[   19.430721] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   50.632430] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link down
[   65.384999] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0: eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[   83.627435] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SS
```

As you can see the wireless adapter is being detected in the lines that start with `usb 1-1.3`, but nothing happens afterwards.

The RPi is powered by an adapter with (I guess) 1.0A, it may be 2.0A.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly doubt this is a power issue considering the size of your wireless card. I run a USB wifi dongle on my Pi off the supplied power adapter just fine.

Do you have any kind of MAC filtering enabled on your router? If so, add the MAC of your Wifi dongle in your router settings.

Other than that:

The settings in wpa_supplicant.conf are wrong. Try running wpa_supplicant manually. First edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and check everything is correct to your network. If it's the default configuration file (a long one with lots of example networks), just create your own configuration file (`my.conf` for example) to look like:

```
ap_scan=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
    # Note you need the quotes around ssid and psk strings
    ssid="YOURSSID"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=WPA RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    psk="YOURPSK"
}
```

Then run wpa_supplicant manually with:

`wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /path/to/your/conf -Dwext`

When that is running, run `dhcpcd -v` to obtain an IP.

Comment: I did what you said (a MAC filter was not present). Now I get a wireless connection (yay!), but only if I start `wpa_supplicant` manually. Just one last question: How do I set things up so that it connects to the wireless network on startup automatically?

Comment: Cool. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect your new config file: `wpa-roam /path/to/your/config` and remove the `wpa-ssid` and `wpa-psk` variables.

Comment: I did, but the wireless network is still not active when rebooting the RPi automatically. Do I need to add the `wpa_supplicant` line somewhere?

Comment: I don't use Debian so I'm not sure how their network configuration works, sorry. You could just stick the `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpcd` commands into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` until you figure out the `interfaces` file :)

Comment: Okay, then I'm going to try to discover it on my own, but *LOTS* of thanks for your really great and awesome help :-)!

Comment: No problem! I think on Debian the local rc script is `/etc/rc.local` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

How do you power your RPi? It could potentially be an power issue. WLAN USB adapters need quite a bit of power!

On the other hand: what are the last few lines of the output of the 'dmesg' command?

Comment: I've updated my question accordingly. Regarding the power issue: The adapter basically works, otherwise it would not be able to find wireless networks - it just does not connect. Does it need more power for connecting than for scanning?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `wpa-roam` with `wpa-conf` in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
wpa-conf /path/to/your/config
```

AFAIK wpa-roam only works with:

```
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

but not with

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Works fine for me ...