# Wifi connection not working (using static IP)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

I'm using Raspbian.

Every time I turn RPi on, the network monitor icon in bottom right corner says, that wlan0 has no connection at all or the connection is limited. wpa_gui gives error *Could not get status from wpa_suplicant*.

These are the config files:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.111
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
iface home inet static
  address 192.168.1.110
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  gateway 192.168.1.1
iface stalk inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_suplicant/wpa_suplicant.conf (also /etc/wpa.config is a link to this one)

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="my_ssid"
    psk="my_pass"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=TKIP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    id_str="home"
    priority=15
}

network={
    ssid=""
    psk=""
    key_mgmt=NONE
    auth_alg=OPEN
    priority=1
    disabled=1
    id_str="stalk"
}
```

FYI: my network is using only static IP and WPA2. The ethernet connection works without problems. The wifi adapter (Modecom mc-un11c) is connected to powered USB hub.

To configure the files I used [this manual](http://manual.siduction.org/en/inet-setup-en.htm#net-set3).

What is wrong, why does the wifi connection not work?

Comment: Try replacing `wpa-roam` with `wpa-conf` in `/etc/network/interfaces` as per this thread: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/start-wireless-network-automatically-on-boot-up-how-to

Comment: nope, this did not work.

Comment: Is `wlan0` up? Check the output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried only setting the SSID and PSK? I was also using a static IP and WPA 2. I had a similar problem to yours, but when I only configured the SSID and PSK it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you using hidden network you have to add:

**wpa-scan-ssid 1**

to /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score -1):

Based on ingo's answer, I thought of using dhcpcd. 
I am Sharing my experience (Likely to be useful to newbee and irritating to masters)
I kept my old /etc/network/interface file as it is.
First, as soon as dhcpcd was started, my ssh connection hanged
After first reboot, it momentarily pinged to old( 192.168.1.2 , see question above) address. But in few seconds ping stopped.
After second reboot, I could ping and ssh 192.168.1.2.
To my surprise, Now had two ips for eth0 and wlan0

```
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 02:81:79:1b:3c:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::81:79ff:fe1b:3c09/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 12:81:79:1b:3c:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 192.168.1.13/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute wlan0 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::1081:79ff:fe1b:3c09/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I think ip address of both interfaces and dhcpcd are allotted.
All IP are pinging and connecting.
What is syntax for writing static wifi (and LAN) ip in dhcpcd?

Comment: **eth0** and **wlan0** have the same ip address `192.168.1.13/24`. This is wrong. Different interfaces must have a unique ip address. I do not understand what you are doing. Please forget `/etc/network/interfaces` and use its default setting without any stanza.

Comment: Both 192.168.1.13 were assigned by dhcpcd. (There is no mention of them in interfaces)

Answer (score -1):

With respect to my question at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/117643/125839 I found that,editing /etc/dhcpcd.conf file (and do not confuse with /etc/dhcp/dhcclient.conf) can force dhcpdcd to give static ip of out choice.
example (add following in /etc/dhcpcd.conf):

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.3/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.1.2/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8
```

also edit /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf for wifi

```
country=IN
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="My_wifi"
    psk="My_Pass"
}
```

With dhcpcd installed and /etc/dhcpcd.conf and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf completes static IP allocation.
Now, /etc/network/interfaces file can only contain declaration of loopback only
Now, my only eth0 starts, wlan0 is not working. Any idea for wrong configuration?

Comment: To make wlan0 work,  i commented out all lines for eth0 in dhcpcd.conf. Only wlan0 lines are active. Now, My eth0 is working( with dhcpcd assigned ip of 192.168.1.13). It does not allot static ip. And wlan0 is still not working. Unless, somebody really explain and help, i am going to conclude that, dhcpcd fails at allotting static ip to my eth0 and wlan0 successfully.

Answer (score -2):

Read 100s of answers for How to setup static wifi on pi
I am summarizing my experience:
Relevant for oragepi / rasberrypi
Why: a pi attached to USB power supply with no 'strings' attached is the goal

- Connect with LAN (Because Wifi is not set / may get broken during trial
- `systemctl disable NetworkManager` (to disable nmtui)
- content of /etc/network/interfaces

  ```
  allow-hotplug eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.1.3
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.1.1



   #auto wlan0
      allow-hotplug wlan0
      iface wlan0 inet static
       address 192.168.1.2
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 192.168.1.1
       wpa-ssid XYZ
       wpa-psk ABC
  ```
- There will be many post saying that gateway line can not be duplicated. But you can
- wpa-ssid and wpa-psk do not need inverted comma
- wpa-psk need not be in Hex
- There will be many post saying that

  - only one of the two is active.
  - eth0 dominating on wlan0.
  - eth0 disconnected disables wlan0.
- But all that is due to `auto eth0` instead use `allow-hotplug eth0`
- `auto` activates by default.
- `allow-hotplug` activates only if connected

No need for wpa-supplicant config files
This way both LAN and wifi works with static ip

Comment: The question is nearly 8 years old. Please note that your answer is not relevant for an up to date Raspberry Pi OS anymore. I don't believe anyone will use such an old operating system and the question has an accepted answer. `NetworkManager` is never used with Raspbian/RaspiOS. Also `/etc/network/interfaces` isn't used since years. There is a hint in it, saying: "*# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'*".

Comment: It is also about orangepi

Comment: This site is only about Raspberry Pi.