# USB Wi-Fi dongle listed in lsusb, wlan0 OK in ifconfig, but no address and all RX dropped

Tags: wifi, retropie, realtek

I am currently trying to make my USB dongle work on the Pi.

I have seen a lot of posts about this dongle, and I am sure it will work, but following all the posts I have found never gives me the same result.

First, I checked `lsusb`:

```
pi@retropie ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n
```

So far, so great...
Then, `ifconfig`:

```
pi@retropie ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3a:1c:e9  
          inet addr:192.168.1.6  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:242 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:92627 (90.4 KiB)  TX bytes:34935 (34.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:100 (100.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:4e:06:1c:1b:94  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:41 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Looks like there is something wrong there...
So, I followed this post: [USB WiFi adapter being detected but no connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9168/usb-wifi-adapter-being-detected-but-no-connection)

I changed `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Then, I rebooted, but nothing changes.. Still the same output from `ifconfig`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
as suggested, I added: 
wpa-ssid "myssid"
wpa-psk "********"
right below iface wlan0 inet dhcp

But

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:4e:06:1c:1b:94  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Only difference is that I have no dropped packets.. But still not connected

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a router?

Comment: I am trying to connect to my belgian internet box, which works with all my devices, and all smartphones and laptops from friends: http://support.en.proximus.be/app/answers/detail/a_id/10325/~/connect-to-the-internet%3A-configure-your-b-box-or-b-box-2-modem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` file what you have is

`auto lo` : `auto` specifies that your that the interface `lo` which stands for `loopback` is going to be up automatically at boot.

`iface lo inet loopback`: this is also part of stanza of `lo`

`iface eth0 inet dhcp` : here, you are telling `eth0` interface is going to be automatically configured via dhcp

If I were you I would also add `auto eth0` | `allow-hotplug eth0` above `iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Now we came to `wlan0` stanza.

Start with adding `auto wlan0` on top of that stanza for getting the interface up on boot if you don't want to do it manually.

The main thing you are doing wrong is you didn't specify anything to connect, you can't expect Pi to enter SSID or password with its own judgment.

So you have to add :

```
wpa-ssid "yourssid"
wpa-psk "yourpassword"
```

right below `iface wlan0 inet dhcp`

For more information : https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: In the `/etc/network/interfaces` from OP, doesn't the wpa_supplicant.conf supply the SSID and PSK for WPA/WPA2 encryption?

Comment: It depends on what's been written inside wpa_supplicant.conf, and its not compulsory to use wpa_supplicant @WineSoaked

Comment: auto eth0 | allow-hotplug eth0 completely screwed my cable connection, I had to remove this line. Currently trying the WLAN part but nothing happens. Restared the Pi, but no connection. I am accessing it with ssh on the cable, even removed the cable, but still not connected

Comment: I had to remove these two lines. Should I create a new answer accept after you added that? REMOVE wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp

Comment: You shouldn't write whole auto eth0 | allow-hotplug eth0, you should write either "auto eth0" or "allow-hotplug eth0" @Waza_Be

Comment: OK, it worked, but as I said in previous comment, I had to remove 2 lines to make it work... Thank a lot for your help.