# I can't connect to my Raspberry Pi until I curl to the connecting device

Tags: raspbian, wireless, headless

I have seen other questions on this board that are similar but I haven't seen an answer that works for me. I have a Raspberry Pi setup so that it can talk to the wireless lan. I am on an Airport Extreme bridged to a ubee modem and I do not have guest mode turned on for the airport extreme so it is NOT in wireless isolation mode. If I have connected with both the wired and wireless lan then I can easily connect to my Pi from any device on my local network using either the wireless ip or the wired ip. However, if I remove the wire and reboot then I can see the internet through the wireless net from the Pi but no other devices on my local lan can see my Pi. What I just discovered today was that if I curl to the ip address of another device, even if it has no web server( like an iPhone) then that device can suddenly see the Pi!

My intention is to have the Pi be headless and host a web page for use only within my local pan. Any help would be appreciated.

I have raspbian installed with all the latest updates, nothing else installed except nginx as I am trying to start from scratch.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="<ssid>"
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP
psk="<psk>"
}
```

Comment: can you post the output of `ip route list` as root?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a solution, but I had a similar problem with my Pi that it couldn't be reached until it initiated a connection. I simply made it do so at boot, problem solved. Edit the `/etc/rc.local` file to add in a `ping` command like so:

```
ping -i 30 -q <ip address of router> > /dev/null &
```

The `-i 30`  makes it send a packet once every 30 seconds, `-q` suppresses output,  self-explanatory, `> /dev/null` hides that last little bit of output, and `&` makes sure it's a background process that runs while you use the system.

Comment: This probably is a solution for many people having problems reaching the Pi from another computer. The ping will put the Pi in the switch's MAC lookup table and keep it refreshed there. The default aging timer in switches is usually 5 minutes. If a switch doesn't hear a packet from a device within that time, it forgets where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'wpa-roam' instead 'wpa-conf'

There is a limited explanation related it on an old answer.

[What's the difference between `wpa-roam` and `wpa-conf` in the /etc/network/interfaces file?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9257/whats-the-difference-between-wpa-roam-and-wpa-conf-in-the-etc-network-inte/9262#9262)